# Can't build boost 1.55 under OSX Mavericks + Xcode 5

Tags: macos, c++11, boost, xcode5, clang

When I try to build boost on my Mac machine, the library itself builds fine but then it is unable to even build the accumulators regression test.  Here's what I do:

```
tar -xzf ../boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
mkdir /tmp/boost
mkdir /tmp/boost/build
mkdir /tmp/boost/install
cd boost_1_55_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags=-std=c++11 cxxflags=-stdlib=libc++ linkflags=-stdlib=libc++ -j2 --prefix=/tmp/boost/install --build-dir=/tmp/boost/build variant=release link=static threading=multi install
cd libs/accumulators/test
../../../b2 toolset=clang cxxflags=-std=c++11 cxxflags=-stdlib=libc++ linkflags=-stdlib=libc++ -j2 --build-dir=/tmp/boost/build
```

the error I get is:

```
clang-darwin.compile.c++ 

/tmp/boost/build/boost/bin.v2/libs/accumulators/test/valarray.test/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/link-static/valarray.o
In file included from valarray.cpp:18:
../../../boost/accumulators/statistics/weighted_mean.hpp:73:13: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'result_type' (aka 'valarray<typename divides<left_value_type, const double>::result_type>')
      : mean(
        ^
../../../boost/accumulators/framework/depends_on.hpp:319:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::accumulators::impl::immediate_weighted_mean_impl<std::__1::valarray<int>, int, boost::accumulators::tag::sample>::immediate_weighted_mean_impl<boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<const boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::accumulators::tag::sample, const std::__1::valarray<int> >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::accumulators::tag::accumulator, boost::accumulators::accumulator_set<std::__1::valarray<int>, boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::weighted_mean (boost::accumulators::immediate), mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, int> >, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> > >' requested here
          : Accumulator(args)
            ^
../../../boost/accumulators/framework/depends_on.hpp:252:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::accumulators::detail::accumulator_wrapper<boost::accumulators::impl::immediate_weighted_mean_impl<std::__1::valarray<int>, int, boost::accumulators::tag::sample>, boost::accumulators::tag::immediate_weighted_mean>::accumulator_wrapper<boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<const boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::accumulators::tag::sample, const std::__1::valarray<int> >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::accumulators::tag::accumulator, boost::accumulators::accumulator_set<std::__1::valarray<int>, boost::accumulators::stats<boost::accumulators::tag::weighted_mean (boost::accumulators::immediate), mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, int> >, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> > >' requested here
```

Is anyone else seeing this?  Is this a known bug with boost?

Comment: Do you know homebrew ? I install all my libraries from there on 10.9. Boost has no problem with brew

Comment: Alas, our process requires that we build the libraries in-house to "guarantee that they are built using the correct compiler and flags".

Comment: Nevertheless, you can edit the boost.rb formula and put your flags. But most importantly, you can have a look of how boost is actually built on mac 10.9 and see what's wrong with your install.

Comment: It's not a bad install, the problem is that I'm trying to get boost to build on a not-yet-supported compiler (clang from Apple LLVM 5.1) using not-yet-support compiler flags (-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++).  I'm out here on the bleeding edge, trying to figure out why the compiler doesn't like this code.  There are other issues that have already been addressed and patched - and the only way I can even get the boost libraries to build is to apply those patches to my 1.55 source.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags=-stdlib=libstdc++ linkflags=-stdlib=libstdc++ -j2 --prefix=/tmp/boost/install --build-dir=/tmp/boost/build variant=release link=static threading=multi install
```

I've got boost to compile on 10.9.2 with those flags, at it appears to pass at least the Accumulators test you mentioned.

Comment: For me, without some contortions, I can't even build the boost libraries, much less any of the regression tests.  I suspect you and I are using different versions of the compiler (I'm using "Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)").  The boost build fails because of known issues (and post-1.55 patches are already available to fix them) but once I apply the patches, yes I can build boost with the flags you specified, but (1) I need to have c++11 enabled, and (2) I need to use libc++ instead of libstdc++.